# AccessViolationException?

Tags: c#, mysql, access-violation

I'm getting this weird AccessViolationException in my C# program that uses a MySQL database connection. I use values from the database to generate an autocorrect facility for a textbox. Here's the code snippet:

```
private void textBoxName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            AutoCompleteStringCollection asc = Database.getSuggestedNames(textBoxName.Text);
            if (asc != null)
                textBoxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = asc;                         
    }
```

The getSuggestedNames(string) method is implemented in Database.cs as follows:

```
public static AutoCompleteStringCollection getSuggestedNames(string namepart)
    {
        string query = "SELECT name FROM worker WHERE name LIKE '%"+namepart+"%';";
        string[] namecolumn = { "name" };
        List<string>[] names = getValues(query,namecolumn);
        AutoCompleteStringCollection namec = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < names[0].Count; i++)
            namec.Add(names[0][i]);
        return namec;
    }
```

The actual query is done with a separate method in the same file called getValues:

```
private static List<string>[] getValues(string query,string[] columnNames)
    {
        if (connection == null)
            initialize();

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[columnNames.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            list[i] = new List<string>();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<columnNames.Length;i++)
                list[i].Add(dataReader[columnNames[i]] + "");
        }

        dataReader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        return list;
    }
```

The exception always occurs when the user enters data into the textbox textBoxName. The error is not very frequent and the call stack shows its the external code that causes the problem. So I assume it should be MySQL that causes the problem.

Can somebody please help me to overcome this problem since there is nothing I can do.

The exact line the error occurs on is line 17 in the following code,which is not much use for me for debugging. Visual Studio does not show any other place. The stack trace shows [external code]. But here it is anyway:

```
1    using System;
2    using System.Collections.Generic;
3    using System.Windows.Forms;
4    
5    namespace LabourManagement
6    {
7        static class ManagementProgram
8        {
9            /// <summary>
10            /// The main entry point for the application.
11            /// </summary>
12            [STAThread]
13            static void Main()
14            {
15                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
16                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
17                Application.Run(new General());
18                         
19            }
20        }
21    }
```

Comment: Please post exact place where the exception is being thrown (which line in your code)...

Comment: I've never used MySqlDataReader but I've used the SQL and ODBC ones.  I'm fairly positive your issue is with list[i].Add(dataReader[columnNames[i]] + "").  When you retrieve the Item using a string, the datareader will return the result as an Object.  You may need to convert the Object to string or it's appropriate column type equivalent before adding it.

Comment: It cannot be. I use this getValue() method as rather a generic method via which I retrieve data throughout my program. I never encounter this problem except when characters are entered to this textbox. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I didn't mean this line that shows error... Put a breakpoint somewhere before error shows up, and use F10/F11 (in VS) to execute your code step by step. Then you will see where exactly in your code exception is thrown

Comment: I know this comment is super late but did you ever solve this? I think the error occurs because your `getValues` method is reentrant. That is, the method could be called again before it has completed, because connecting to and querying a DB are probably slower than the user can type another character. It's possible that call #2 executes `cmd.ExecuteReader()` after call #1 has executed `connection.Close()`.

Comment: You can avoid the problem like this: (a) ensure that `getValues` is non-reentrant (eg. use a class field as a flag). (b) avoid calling `getValues` when its results will be thrown away immediately due to another keypress: only update the string collection after the user has stopped typing for 500 ms or longer (use a timer that is reset by the `TextChanged` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i was working on a DataGridView auto-complete feature. at last, i discovered that the strange problem 'Access violation reading location 0x00000000' is due to a small semi-bug in .net which cause this exception if you add a `null` string to a AutoCompleteStringCollection!

So, the important thing when you are loading auto complete data from a source like as a database is to ensure avoid/skip `null` items when adding data to the collection.

Edit your code as following (note the if condition: `if (names[0][i]!=null) ...`):

```
public static AutoCompleteStringCollection getSuggestedNames(string namepart)
{
    string query = "SELECT name FROM worker WHERE name LIKE '%"+namepart+"%';";
    string[] namecolumn = { "name" };
    List<string>[] names = getValues(query,namecolumn);
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namec = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < names[0].Count; i++)
        if (names[0][i]!=null) namec.Add(names[0][i]);
    return namec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a ComboBox where i edited the item collect during a SelectedIndexChanged event. The stack trace will be unmanaged code, but editing the ComboBox.items collection was definitely the culprit. Maybe editing the AutocompleteSource items is causing your issue (since "Suggest" mode works like a ComboBox).